# Prove Path Space is homotopy equivalent to Space ($PX \simeq X$)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

When $X$ is a path-connected topological space and $PX$ is the path space of $X$ endowed with the compact-open topology, it is a well-known fact that $PX$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$. However, **how do we prove $PX \simeq X$?** This turns out to be very important in topological motion planning, which is a new area of interest for me. Below is my attempt at a proof that arrives at $PX \simeq *$, which I know to only be true in the case of a pointed space $(X, *)$, when any path $\gamma_i$ has $\gamma_i(0) = *$. If someone could help me understand the continuity/logical issues in my proof that would be greatly appreciated.

Proof:
Since $X$ is path-connected, then there exists $f_{ab} \colon I \longrightarrow X$ continuous functions with $f_{ab}(0) = a$ and $f_{ab}(1) = b$ for all $a,b \in X$. Now fix $b = b_0$. The family of paths $\{f_{ab_0} | a\in X\}$ connect every point in $X$ with the point $b_0$. Thus, we can construct a "shrinking to end point" homotopy as follows:
$$H\colon I \times I \longrightarrow PX $$
$$H_t(s) =  f_{ab_0}(1-(1-t)(1-s))$$
So we can see $$H_0(s) =  f_{ab_0}(1-(1-s)) = f_{ab_0}(s)$$
$$H_1(s) =  f_{ab_0}(1) = c_{b_0}$$
$$\implies f_{ab_0} \simeq c_{b_0} \implies f_{ab_m} \simeq c_{b_m}.$$
Where $c_x$ is the constant map at $x$. Thus, we conclude that every path is homotopic to the constant map at its endpoint. Now fix the point $a = a_0$, allowing b to change and consider a similar homotopy:
$$V\colon I \times I \longrightarrow PX $$
$$V_t(s) =  f_{a_0b}(st)$$
$$\implies f_{a_0b} \simeq c_{a_0} \implies f_{a_nb} \simeq c_{a_n}.$$
Now note that $c_{a_n} \simeq f_{a_nb_m} \simeq c_{b_m}$ for all $m \in M$ and $n \in N$.

Therefore, any path is homotopic to the constant map at one of its endpoints and any constant maps are homotopic by transitivity, so all of the paths in $PX$ can be simultaneously deformed to a single constant map. Thus, $PX \simeq *$.

Comment: The proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189811/path-space-is-contractible?rq=1) can be adapted to your setting, if you just notice that your paths may not all be based at the same (starting) point.

Comment: Thank you for linking that similar question. My two homotopies build on that idea, so I imagine shrinking all paths (except paths based at $a_0$) to their corresponding $b_n$ and then using all paths based at $a_0$ to move those constant paths to $a_0$ using homotopy $V$. In this way it is something of a concatenation of homotopies.

Comment: I would suggest considering $\pi: PX \to X\subseteq PX$ such that $\gamma \longmapsto \gamma(0)$ and showing it is homotopic to the identity. One way to do this is to consider $H(t,\gamma)(s) = \gamma(s(1-t))$, as in that post. Then $H(0,\gamma) = \gamma$ while $H(1,\gamma) = \gamma(0)$. The only difference is that $\gamma(0)$ is not a fixed point of $X$.